# Bootstrap modal doesn't show by dynamically added button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window

```
<div class="modal fade" id="comment-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
                            aria-labelledby="Modal" aria-hidden="true">
... content
</div>
```

Buttons in basic html show modal window properly:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-xs comment-edit" type="button" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#comment-modal">
          <i class="fa fa-edit" title='edit'></i>
</button>
```

But same buttons added dynamically( via ajax call) show only a fade page and dosn't show any dialog. But then I inspect code in Chrome the modal window looks showned.

```
 <div class="modal fade in" id="comment-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
           aria-labelledby="Modal" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
    ... content
    </div>
```

And if first click to non dynamically added button and after then to dynamically added button then modal is showed properly.

Comment: Ever figure anything out here?  I've got the same type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

that `button` won't work. Judging from your code:

you are opening a `button` tag and closing it with an `I tag`. Do things work that way? I don't think so. 
Then You are not targeting anything. Modal buttons have a `data-target` element pointing to the `id` of the `modal-div`. so give your modal div and id and use data-target to the button in other to point towards it.

In your button: `title attribute` doesn't have a closing tag. Maybe this will solve most of your problems.

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-xs comment-edit" type="button" 
   data-toggle="modal" class="fa fa-edit" title="edit" data-target="#ModalDiv">
     Button Name
</button>



<div class="modal fade in" id="comment-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
       aria-labelledby="Modal" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;" id="ModalDiv">
... content
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated  my html. It was copied with errors. Sorry. Still the same problem.